# A more formal adjective to 'sneaky'

Tags: word-choice

What would be an adjective that describes a person or a company that purposely hides information for its advantage, but to another's disadvantage? I'm feeling there's a word more appropriate than `deceptive`, `dishonest` or `insincere`, more along the lines of `sneaky`.

An example might be a services company that overcharges and purposely does not issue a time breakdown of their bill.

Comment: Also see [A word for advantages gained by sabotaging competitors](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65800),

Answer (score 3):

I might call them *[underhanded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underhanded?show=1&t=1341116923)*

> marked by secrecy, chicanery, and deception : not honest and aboveboard : sly

or *[deceitful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deceitful)*

> having a tendency or disposition to deceive

Comment: I'd go with deceitful, too.

Answer (score 2):

There is *calculating*, which has definitions of ["selfishly scheming"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/calculating) or ["crafty, coldly scheming, or conniving."](http://www.answers.com/topic/calculating)

There is also [*disingenuous*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disingenuous), which has one definition of "not straightforward or candid; insincere or calculating."

Answer (score 2):

After reading your example sentence – the one about the dishonest utility company – one word that sprang into my mind was ***corrupt***.  Using a thesaurus from there, I found these other candidates: ***unscrupulous***, ***fraudulent***, ***unprincipled***, ***untrustworthy***.  A more informal term might be ***crooked***.

Out of those, I like *untrustworthy* as applied to an individual, and perhaps *fraudulent* when talking about an institution or company.  Quite often, *corrupt* seems to be used to describe dishonest leaders and authorities (such as politicians, or a police force). From NOAD:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about *sly*? It is a long-established word but without the slangy feel of *sneaky*.